# How to change the color of errors/warnings count from tab/explorer in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to **change the color** of the numeric count of **erros/warnings badge** in the editor **tab or explorer** in vscode. I attach two images for disclosure

[image]

[image]

I've searched in the VS Code documentation for help but I've found nothing aside from the git badge decorators properties which changes the color of git status (M, U, S...) in the tab. It doesn't changes the color of the errors number. Other thing is the color of the numbers is red when there are errors and yellow for warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way that you can do this without also changing the colour of the file name, but here it is (put in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson)):

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "list.errorForeground": "#ff0000",
    "list.warningForeground": "#ff0000",
},
```